# How to check if a timer handler thread is running in POSIX

Tags: linux, multithreading, timer, pthreads, posix

We are developing a kernel driver and corresponding test cases (in user land) and used timers in our code. `Malloc` is almost not available. Timers are set up by `SIGEV_THREAD` so new threads are created.

According to the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863192/safe-method-to-wait-for-all-thread-timer-callbacks-completion) and [here](https://sourceware.org/ml/libc-help/2009-07/msg00069.html), it is hard to implement a general clean up system. So I am trying to define a framework with coding rules to deal with this.

In this method, I need to count the number of running handlers of a specific timer. In kernel, I can use `try_to_del_timer_sync()` and re-add to achieve this, but I cannot find a method in userland, especially `POSIX`.

Linux-specific methods are also welcome.

Comment: Probably a duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3475750/694576

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate. Even I got the number of all threads, I don't know how it is triggered. And I need a method to find out which timer triggered that thread.

Comment: Your questions use-case is "*I need to count the number of running handlers.*"